# Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe' problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I am using Python jupyterLab. My computer is 32 bit. "Advertising.csv" when running this dataset I get this error:

> Cannot cast array data from dtype ('int64') to dtype ('int32')
>   according to the rule 'safe'

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
ad = pd.read_csv("Advertising.csv", usecols=[1,2,3,4]) 
df = ad.copy()   
df.head() 
import seaborn as sns
sns.pairplot(df, kind ="reg")
```

How to fix ?

Comment: what line throws the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
ad = pd.read_csv("Advertising.csv", usecols=[1,2,3,4], dtype=np.int32)
```

Comment: Thank you but when doing so, numpy works.                                           
import numpy as np
ad = pd.read_csv ("Advertising.csv", usecols = [1,2,3,4], dtype = np.float32).
But the problem is in part 2. import seaborn as sns
sns.pairplot (df, kind = "reg")

Comment: @EycanÖzdemir what's your seaborn version? Use ` 0.10.1` and see if the error still persists. Run `pip install --upgrade seaborn` to upgrade

Comment: Oh you are perfect. My problem is now resolved. Thank you so much.. :) :)